# What are the well known methods for moving data around the layers in MVP

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-binding, mvp

I'm working on an application where the MVP pattern is employed. It's still early in development, so I still have the luxury of reflecting back critically on the different design choices.

**The Model** is composed of some structs and some API functions that operate on them, for clarity's sake, let's say this is the Model:

```
struct ComplexNumber {
    double real;
    double imag;
};

Complex_Add(ComplexNumber x, ComplexNumber y);
Complex_Mul(ComplexNumber x, ComplexNumber y);
```

Then comes **the View**. I'm using only primitive types here.

```
class IComplexView {
public:

    virtual double GetReal1() = 0;
    virtual double GetImag1() = 0;

    virtual double GetReal2() = 0;
    virtual double GetImag2() = 0;
    // Setters snipped
};
```

Now in **the Presenter**, as far as I could understand, I'd have a few methods for View-to-Model and Model-to-View data translation. I typically have a ReadView() and an UpdateView() methods. So that part of the presenter would look something very close to this:

```
class ComplexPresenter {
    ICopmlexView view;
    ComplexNumber x;
    ComplexNumber y;

    // ...

    static void ReadView() {
        x.real = view.GetReal1();
        x.imag = view.GetImag1();

        y.real = view.GetReal2();
        y.imag = view.GetImag2();
    }
}
```

`UpdateView()` would be the other way round so that the view is populated from the model.

With that setup, the question is:
*Is there some "clever" way to bind a variable/property from the view to one in the model other than the straightforward one above?*

The problem I see with this is the relatively big amount of added code just for moving data around. First we have the acessors in the IView and then the ReadView() and UpdateView() methods. I think a script could be hooked up to a build event and auto-generate all this code, but I was hoping there would be other alternatives that I'm failing to notice.

Another approach would be to just drop the MVP completely, or to be specific, drop the presenter, and just have a UI<->Logic separation and that's it. The obvious drawback is the stronger coupling, but on the other hand, it will probably incur noticeably less amount of code.

Comment: Have a look at the [Humble View](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#HumbleView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVP variant that you have described may be reffered to as `Passive View` - have a look at [Martin Fowler's entry about it here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html). its drawback indeed is lots of boilerplate code to sync model and view. an alternative using some `data binding` mechanism would be  [`Supervising Controller`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/SupervisingPresenter.html) or [`Presentation Model` (aka `View Model`)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html).

> drop the presenter, and just have a UI<->Logic separation and that's it

one danger here is that binding mechanism may not be able to handle complex cases

In general, consider these two solutions:

- `Presentation Model` could employ two layers of bindings: *view-to-presentation-model* and *presentation-model-to-domain-model* bindings. it maintains lower coupling but implementing these two mechanism may be tedious itself.
- `Supervising Controller` uses *view-to-domain-model* bindings and itself handles only complex cases that cannot be handled by binding mechanism, so you get best of both worlds.